# Scale whole layout android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

***that is my problem in relative-layout:***

1. i have some image views that some part of each imageview is out of
   display with negative margin.
2. i design this layout in a display dimension that shown in left side
   and that is OK.
3. but in other display demensions some parts of views that i dont want
   to be shown will be shown [like right image]. (or in smaller
   displays some parts not shown).
4. so. i want just wanted box of layout will be visible in different
   display sizes and be scaled according to display dimensions.

Sorry i know the problem is involved ;)

[image]

i need just visible part of layout scaled in various display sizes, also want views be separate to animate them.
that is one arrows sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="4000dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:rotation="15"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/img_rct_header"
        android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-120dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:rotation="195"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_tall"
        android:id="@+id/img_arw_in_sore"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="815dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8450dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:rotation="195"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_svg"
        android:id="@+id/img_arw_in_tafsir"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="161dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-1150dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:rotation="195"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_svg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/img_arw_out_tafsir"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-272dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="4000dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:rotation="15"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/img_rct_footer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-800dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-120dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks for your help ;)

Comment: upload your images

Comment: There seems no answer available for my questions. I found a library that did not solve my problem but maybe resolve some problems like this:
https://github.com/intuit/sdp/blob/master/sdp-android/src/main/res/layout/sdp_example.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is pretty complex. If all you want is to have this as a background that will look the same in different screen sizes, I'd suggest that you draw that background separately, save it as a high quality png, and then put it in one ImageView, without all the hassle of margins and rotation.

Comment: @Solivan I'm sorry, but I didn't exactly understand what you mean. Could you please explain more? (Maybe show more detailed images)

Comment: I saw your edit. Please post your whole xml, not just that imageview.

Comment: thanks again but the problem is that I want to animate views separately and it is not possible with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the background of layout to that picture in order not to show it in dp.

The dp size is like the pixel of screen and its getting smaller and bigger in other devices try using the value `match_parent` instead of `4000dp`

The best way is to use apps like picsart or picsay. Just put all the pictures in one picture edit the picture then make that the background of the whole layout with these values

```
layout_width="match_parent"
layout_height="match_parent"
```

but if you want to animate them you must add the layout to another layout 
and give them `layout_weight`